# Get only a column in a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get only the "User" column in this website?
https://datarecovery.com/rd/default-passwords/

I tried to do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = "https://datarecovery.com/rd/default-passwords/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
for tag in soup.find_all("span", "paraEight"):
    tag = str(tag)
    print (tag)
```

But I realized that EACH column has the "paraEight" class value so I got all the values of each columns.

UPDATE:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
for tag in soup.select(".table-responsive table tr td:nth-of-type(5) span"):
    tag = str(tag)
    print (tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you have

1. Find all rows from table
2. Then find  tag and in your case the user comes at position 5 so make check and that's all, 
   Here is code sample

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request

    url = "https://datarecovery.com/rd/default-passwords/"

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        all_text = []
        ct = 0
        for td in tr:
            ct += 1
            text = td.get_text(strip=True)
            if ct == 5:
                print(text)
    #output as: User
    #            root
    #            tech
    #            SNMPWrite
    #            (none)
    #            (none)
    #            DOCSIS_APP
    #            admin
```

Comment: Ei! That's a good point, but you mispelled. You wrote 4 but actually it's "5" the value to write.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if beautifulsoup supports the full features of CSS selector, but can you try finding the elements with the selector:

`.table-responsive table tr td:nth-of-type(5) span`

I tried this on the page you linked and it gives all the spans containing user data (e.g. 'root', 'tech', etc.) for the user column

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I tried it. But it only returns me the first user value. I edited the question with the code you wrote

Comment: @AllExJ really weird, I tried it with JQuery on the page itself and it returned all the results but as you say, with BS4 it only returns the first. Quite odd. Anyway, user above got your answer, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Tried it with lxml module and xpath. I think its almost there.

```
import urllib.request
from lxml import etree

url = "https://datarecovery.com/rd/default-passwords/"

htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)

user_list = []

xpathparent = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr'
xpathselector = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/span'
table_user = tree.xpath(xpathparent)
for item in table_user:
    x_path = (tree.getpath(item))
    user = tree.xpath(x_path + '/td[5]/span')
    if len(user) > 0:
        user_name = user[0].text
    else:
        user_name = ''
    user_list.append(user_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract the User column only as all the rows & columns have the same class `paraEight` and they are not distinguishable as of now. But If you assigned them a different `class name` or `id`, then you will be able to scrap them.